# Listening for angularjs broadcast events in a non-angular manner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I'm just curious if the following is possible, and if so how to achieve it. If I have a third party AngularJS library which broadcasts/emits events on the $rootScope, is it possible to listen for these events using plain old javascript? And is it also possible to listen for angular events using some other framework (e.g. backbone, react.js, etc)?

Comment: It depends how old...

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you referring to the version of AngularJS?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from decorating the $rootScope, and overriding $emit and $broadcast functions to send events wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

That is the possibility of angular to be operating with other javascript component.
i think we it is possible with directive and $watch.

$rootScope :($watch)  <------> DOM event  () <--------> Other modules